# Elasticsearch and NEST (searching with spaces)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am searching with spaces and the system fails. Is there any reliable means of using NEST with spaces and special chars?

eg partnumbersearch = 'PM BAS C' The spaces stop if working.

Code -

```
 var searchDataResults = client.Search<RowDef>(s =>    
s.Index("myindex").AllTypes().From(0).Size(10).
Query(q =>   q.Term(p => p.manpartnumber, partnumberSearch) &&q.Term(p => p.shopname, shopSearch)));
```

Comment: %20 works in curl for the space but fails in .NET.

Comment: var searchDataResults = client.Search<Row>(s => s.Index("myindex").AllTypes().From(0).Size(10).
                                                           Query(q => q.Match(m=>m.OnField(p=>p.manpartnumber).Query(partnumberSearch)))); This works but how to code for multi fields?

Comment: What does it mean "system fails"?

Comment: search not working all related to how nest understands. I think this is all related to multi mapping, I think the field PM BAS is not seen as one field but somehow two. The results are just inconsistent. What is needed is a means to search fields such as PM BAS or PM 1/2 or PM_BAS - the space, ;/ etc all causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

I finally answered this by building a hex key. Elastissearch has some kind of mapping for special chars. I worked around this by converting strings to hex and storing them and then searching against the string. This is a workaround but works. I could not find any proper documents explaining how to handle special chars.